# Why can Ruby Procs sometimes return and sometimes it is an error?

Tags: ruby

Two very similar examples in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150207083555/https://reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas):

```
def proc_return
  Proc.new { return "Proc.new"}.call
  return "proc_return method finished"
end

def lambda_return
  lambda { return "lambda" }.call
  return "lambda_return method finished"
end

puts proc_return
puts lambda_return

# => Proc.new
# => lambda_return method finished
```

and

```
def generic_return(code)
  code.call
  return "generic_return method finished"
end

puts generic_return(Proc.new { return "Proc.new" })
puts generic_return(lambda { return "lambda" })

# => *.rb:6: unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
# => generic_return method finished
```

Why is this permitted in `proc_return`

```
Proc.new { return "Proc.new"}.call
```

but (something equivalent to) this is not premitted in `generic_return`

```
code = Proc.new { return "Proc.new" }
code.call
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `proc` as `lambda` is a closure. Closures remember the environment when they were created.
One of the differences between `proc` as `lambda` that if you call `return` inside `proc` it will return from the block (or blocks) of code when it was created. `lambda` returns only from its own block of code.

Here the environment is a method `proc_return`

```
def proc_return
  Proc.new { return "Proc.new"}.call
  return "proc_return method finished"
end
```

While here the environment is a global namespace:

```
def generic_return(code)
  code.call
  return "generic_return method finished"
end

puts generic_return(Proc.new { return "Proc.new" })
```

Let's make it obvious:

```
proc_object = Proc.new { return "Proc.new" }

puts generic_return(proc_object)
```

`proc_object` remember that it was created in a global environment when you call it inside `generic_return` environment, it tries to exit the global one.

You can get the same error just typing `return` in `irb` console:

```
$ irb
2.5.1 :001 > return
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):1
LocalJumpError (unexpected return)
2.5.1 :002 >
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a good mnemonic that I use:

- "`Proc`" rhymes with "*block*", so `Proc` behaves like a block.
- "*lambda*" and "*method*" are both Greek, so lambda behaves like a method.

`return` in a method returns from the method itself, therefore, `return` in a lambda returns from the lambda itself.

`return` in a block returns from the closest lexically enclosing method, therefore `return` in a `Proc` returns from the closest lexically enclosing method.

In your second example, *there is no* lexically enclosing method to return from, therefore you get a `LocalJumpError`.

By the way, the *other* aspect where lambdas behave like methods and `Procs` behave like blocks is that lambdas have strict argument binding (like methods) and `Proc`s have loose argument binding (like blocks).